# AWS Lambda JSON to DynamoDB KeyError Serializing JSON

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am setting up my lambda function on AWS and want to insert my JSON into the DynamoDB (NoSQL). I think it has to do with the serialization of the JSON (decimal_serializer), but I might be wrong. Thanks for help!

I get following error while serializing this data:

**Error MSG:**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'male_confidence'",
  "errorType": "KeyError"
}
```

**JSON DATA to INSERT:**

```
{
  "device_id": "abc876",
  "recorded_at": "1496136878",
  "customers": [
    {
      "male_confidence": "0.2",
      "female_confidence": "0.8"
    },
    {
      "male_confidence:": "0.1",
      "female_confidence": "0.9"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Lambda Function Handler**

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    for customer in event['customers']:
        client.put_item(TableName="cv_data_1", Item={'device_id': {"S": event['device_id']}, 'male_confindence': {"N": customer['male_confidence']}, 'female_confidence': {"N": customer['female_confidence']}, "timestamp":{ "N": event['recorded_at']}})
    print('Successfully processed %s items.' % str(len(event['customers'])))
```

**AWS Output Log Error (Detail):**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

09:23:38
Traceback (most recent call last):

09:23:38
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 463, in <module>

09:23:38
main()

09:23:38
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 459, in main

09:23:38
handle_event_request(request_handler, invokeid, event_body, context_objs, invoked_function_arn)

09:23:38
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 240, in handle_event_request

09:23:38
result = to_json(result)

09:23:38
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 215, in to_json

09:23:38
return json.dumps(obj, default=decimal_serializer)

09:23:38
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps

09:23:38
**kw).encode(obj)

09:23:38
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode

09:23:38
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

09:23:38
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode

09:23:38
return _iterencode(o, 0)

09:23:38
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 104, in decimal_serializer

09:23:38
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

09:23:38
TypeError: <FrameSummary file /var/task/lambda_function.py, line 8 in lambda_handler> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: From the error message, it appears that the`male_confidence` is missing in one of the `customer`. (No pun intended). Can you just print the `event` in the lambda handler so that you can see what data `event` contains? The output will be in cloudwatch logs.

Comment: `{'device_id': 'abc876', 'recorded_at': '1496136878', 'customers': [{'male_confidence': '0.2', 'female_confidence': '0.8'}, {'male_confidence:': '0.1', 'female_confidence': '0.9'}]}` , but if I output `print(customer)`in the loop it returns me the `dict`see below.

Comment: I printed `customer['male_confidence']` in the loop and it returns me `0.2`, the second loop breaks with the error above.

Comment: `{'device_id': 'abc876', 'recorded_at': '1496136878', 'customers': [{'male_confidence': '0.2', 'female_confidence': '0.8'}, {'male_confidence:': '0.1', 'female_confidence': '0.9'}]}
HELLO
{'male_confidence': '0.2', 'female_confidence': '0.8'}
#####
0.2
0.8
HELLO
{'male_confidence:': '0.1', 'female_confidence': '0.9'}
'male_confidence': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
    mc = customer['male_confidence']
KeyError: 'male_confidence'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
  "male_confidence:": "0.1",
  "female_confidence": "0.9"
```

**"male_confidence:"**

Comment: THANKS ALOT! I was going crazy that `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo after `male_confidence:`, note the extra `:`. Try this

```
{
  "device_id": "abc876",
  "recorded_at": "1496136878",
  "customers": [
    {
      "male_confidence": "0.2",
      "female_confidence": "0.8"
    },
    {
      "male_confidence": "0.1",
      "female_confidence": "0.9"
    }
  ]
}
```